# External URLs are being appended at the end of blog post URLs

Tags: url

I need some help with this as it drives me mad.

Some blog posts have an external URL appended to them:
https://www.my-site.com/blog-post/www.external-site.com

I get hundreds of such pages from one single external URL.

Any ideas what might be causing this? It is not happening with all external URLs. Just this one. I've even checked if it was added with the protocol (http://) in front and there aren't any such issues.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that you're seeing these in your Analytics reports? This is almost certainly an issue where inside one or more of your posts' content, you have a link to `www.external-site.com`, without the `http://`. I've seen this often.